# Issue saving a PDF file as BLOB

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I am trying to save a PDF file as blob im MySQL database. The problem takes place when I save the file into the database it lays out a syntax error so I had to add slashes to it.

```
    $user_id      = sanitizeInt   ($user_id     );
    $file_content = addslashes    ($file_content);

    $query = "INSERT INTO `locker`.`files`(`id`, `user_id`, `file_name`, `file_content`) VALUES (NULL, $user_id, 'some_name.pdf', '$file_content');";
```

But when I want to download it later on I do the opposit. I query then use remove slahes

```
        $query = "SELECT `files`.`file_content`, `files`.`file_name` FROM `files` WHERE `files`.`id` = $id LIMIT 0 , 1";

        $record = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

        return stripslashes($record["file_content"]);
```

When I output the PDF I get an empty file.

Comment: What happens when the PDF contains "');drop table `files`;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just solved the problem.

I removed stripslashes and it worked as a charm.

Comment: That's good, you should use `mysql_real_escape_string()` instead of `addslashes` though

Comment: You only need to scape the string because you're writing text into a statement. The blob file doesn't get saved with them. This said for future references